# Mistake in my proof: what is the normalisation factor of the surface integral of a sphere?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I was trying to prove

$$ {1\over \varepsilon} \int_{\partial B(a,\varepsilon)} f dS = {1\over r} \int_{\partial B(a,r)} f dS$$

where $0<\varepsilon < r$  and $f$ is harmonic on $\mathbb R^2$ and $n$ is the normal vector to the sphere.

Here is what I did:

(0) I use the equation 
$$ \int_{D}(f\Delta g - g \Delta f)dV = \int_{\partial D}\left( f {\partial g \over \partial n} - g {\partial f \over \partial n}\right) dS$$
and let $g(x) = \log \|x-a\|$. (this is a radial harmonic function)

(1) I calculated that ${\partial g \over \partial n} = 1$ (this is probably correct, I suspect my mistake to be later in the calculation)

(2) I note that $\int_{B(a,r) \setminus B(a,\varepsilon)} (f \Delta G - G \Delta f)dV  = 0$ because both $f$ and $g$ are harmonic

(3) I showed that $$ \int_{\partial B(a,r)} g {\partial f \over \partial n} dS = 0$$

(4) I put (1)-(3) together so that

$$ 0 = \int_{B(a,r) \setminus B(a,\varepsilon)} (f \Delta G - G \Delta f)dV  = \int_{\partial B(a,r) \sqcup \partial B(a,\varepsilon)} f dS$$

But this results in

$$ \int_{\partial B(a,\varepsilon)} f dS = \int_{\partial B(a,r)} f dS$$

and there is one problem with that:

I am missing the factors of ${1\over \varepsilon}$ and ${1\over r}$.

Hence my question is:

> How can I calculate the normalisation of the surface integral of the sphere?

Comment: Is there a typo in your equation you would like to prove? There is no g...

Comment: @sranthrop No, steps (1) and (2) show how $g$ gets canceled out.

Comment: This is what you wrote: I was trying to prove
$$ {1\over \varepsilon^{n-1}} \int_{\partial B(a,\varepsilon)} f dS = {1\over r^{n-1}} \int_{\partial B(a,r)} f dS$$

where $0<\varepsilon < r$ and $g(x) = \log \|x-a\|$ and $f$ is harmonic on $\mathbb R^2$. 

My question is, what does this equation has to do with $g$? And what is $n$?

Comment: @sranthrop Oh, now I see. I should edit the question.

Comment: @sranthrop Is it better now? :)

Comment: And $n$? Do you mean that $f$ is harmonic in $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: @sranthrop If you are referring to ${\partial \over \partial n}$ then that's the directional derivative in the direction of the normal vector to the sphere...

Comment: No, I am referring to $\varepsilon^{{\color{red} n}-1}$ and $r^{{\color{red} n}-1}$

Comment: @sranthrop Sorry that's another typo that sneaked into my question: I am doing two cases, $n=2$ and $n>2$ and in this question $n$ should be $2$ everywhere, I will edit the question immediately! Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: The sign mistake comes from the integral over $\partial B(a,r)\sqcup\partial B(a,\varepsilon)$: you have to take orientation into account. The missing $r$ and $\varepsilon$ have to do with the normalization of the surace measures.

Comment: Your question still does not make sense, since there is no normal vector in your equation...

Comment: @sranthrop Not in the equation I want to show but there was one in the equation I want to use to prove the equation I want to prove: I eliminated the normal vector in (1) and (3).

Comment: @Etienne Thank you so much for your help. And I'm sorry for the late reply, I didn't see your comment until now.

Comment: @Etienne I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: @Etienne Can I use the formula [here on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_integral) and use $\mathbf{x}=(x,y)$ so that ${\partial \mathbf{x}\over \partial x} = (1,0)$ and ${\partial \mathbf{x}\over \partial y} = (0,1)$? The only thing I'm not clear about is how to calculate the cross product in two dimensions and how to calculate a "surface" integral in two dimensions... which make me wonder: am I really calculating a line integral?

Comment: In fact I was wrong for the second mistake : the missing $\varepsilon$ and $r$ come from $\frac{\partial g}{\partial n}$, which is $1/r$ on one circle and $1/\varepsilon$ on the other one.

Comment: @Etienne I am trying to calculate this but I get the constant $1$ function. I posted all my calculations [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1098460/calculating-the-directional-derivative-normal-to-s1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (4) I put (1)-(3) together so that
>   $$
> 0 = \int_{B(a,r) \setminus B(a,\varepsilon)} (f \Delta G - G \Delta f)\, dV
>   = \int_{\partial B(a,r) \sqcup \partial B(a,\varepsilon)} f\, dS
> $$

It appears you've lost the normal derivative of $g$. That is, the right-hand integral should be
$$
0 = \int_{B(a,r) \setminus B(a,\varepsilon)} (f \Delta G - G \Delta f)\, dV
  = \int_{\partial B(a,r) \sqcup \partial B(a,\varepsilon)} f \frac{\partial g}{\partial n}\, dS,
$$
and of course $\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial n}(x) = \dfrac{1}{\|x - a\|}$.

Comment: Thank you. But I didn't lose it: In step (1) I calculated ${\partial g\over \partial n}=1$. I had calculated ${\partial\over \partial x_i}\log \|x-a\| = {x_i - a_i \over \|x-a\|^2}$ for each coordinate and $n = (x_1-a_1,x_2-a_2)$. When I take the dot product I get $1$...

Comment: I did it several times to find possible mistakes but I can't find any :(

Comment: I posted my calculations [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1098460/calculating-the-directional-derivative-normal-to-s1).

Comment: @user174981: Doesn't $n$ refer to a unit vector? If so, then $n = (x - a)/\|x - a\|$, while you've used $n = x - a$. If the normal derivative $\partial g/\partial n$ were constant, $g$ would be a the norm function itself up to an additive constant. :)

Comment: Yes exactly, I noticed after posting my comment. Thank you for your help!